# Wordpress featured image custom crop rejection

Tags: wordpress, image, crop, wordpress-featured-image

I am currently unable to use my newly cropped images in the media library as my featured post images. When I go to selected the featured image I see and click on the cropped image. However, once the image is selected the cropped image seems to be reverted to the full size image with auto crop.

I added a custom thumbnail size in my functions file of 360, 360, true.

Any idea why this may be happening?

Thanks in advance and happy holidays!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say in your function.php you have `add_image_size('my-new-size-name', 360, 360, true);`

To get the cropped image you have to use `get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'my-new-size-name')` or `the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'my-new-size-name')` if you want to display it.

You can't select the cropped image from the admin panel and use it as a featured image. The way it appears depends on your theme.

So if in your theme there is `the_post_thumbnail()` it will take the full size no matter what.

If you don't want to put an extra code in your theme then you have to crop yout image yourself and upload it again and set it as featured image.

Comment: Thanks, I used a similar method that unfortunately isn't working yet.



`$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    

$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'custom-thumb');
    

echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'"><img src="'.$thumb_url[0].'" class="img-responsive"></a>';`


Any idea why this still isn't allowing me to use my personally cropped thumbnail?

Comment: Your code is correct. What is the results using this code ? Go to your uploads folder (wp-content->uploads) and see if your image is there. You should see ie your-image.png, your-image-360x360.png with the last one being your cropped image to your desired dimensions. If is there it means that your image is being cropped so the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, the cropping is working fine and all the images are in the folder. What else might cause this problem? The image is selectable inside the featured image tap. However, once clicked and confirmed it ignores the request and pulls in the image, but in its full size form and auto crops it instead of just grabbing the cropped version that was initially clicked on.

Comment: Strange. Sorry but I can't think a solution. Is working on my localhost environment.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in while loop or anywhere where you want to show thumbnail:

```
the_post_thumbnail(array(300,300));
```